# Asp.net MVC Visible/hide

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, hide, show

That's a simple task in ASP.NET WebForms:If you want to show/hide a control all you need to do is set "Visible=true" or "Visible=false".

However,i dont know how to accomplish that in MVC.I have a DIV in my view that needs to show/hide,depending validation on server.

```
<div class="divWarning">
Test
</div>
```

I need to show or hide it dynamic,but needs to be controlled by server.

Any ideias?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<% if(Model.ShowYourDiv){ %>

   <div class="divWarning">
   Test
   </div>

<% } %>
```

The div will only show when the `ShowYourDiv` property is `true`.